# iOS delegation doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm trying to implement delegate method between 2 classes in my app but the delegated method is not called.

Here is my code :

PBPartnersService.h

```
@protocol PBPartnersServicesDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void) didReceiveNewsDatasFromPartners:(NSDictionary *)Datas;

@end
```

Then I make my @property :

```
@interface PBPartnersServices : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, weak) id<PBPartnersServicesDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In my PBPartnersService.m I call my delegate method (when I print self.delegate I get 'nil') :

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceiveNewsDatasFromPartners:)]) {
                [self.delegate didReceiveNewsDatasFromPartners:obj];
}
```

In my other class PBTicketsService.h I instantiate the first one :

```
@interface PBTicketsService : NSObject <PBPartnersServicesDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *ticketList;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) PBPartnersServices *partnersServices;
    - (void) prepareForDelegate;

@end
```

I made a method in PBTicketsService.m to set the partnersServices as a delegate :

```
- (void) prepareForDelegate{
    self.partnersServices = [[PBPartnersServices alloc] init];
    [self.partnersServices setDelegate:self];
}
```

and then I have my function who is never call :

```
-(void) didReceiveNewsDatasFromPartners:(NSDictionary *)Datas{

}
```

Comment: Where do you call `prepareForDelegate`?

Comment: And check within `prepareForDelegate` if `self.partnersServices` is not `nil` when you try to set the delegate.

Comment: I call prepareForDelegate in my home view controller here : 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.ticketsServices = [[PBTicketsService alloc] init];
    [self.ticketsServices prepareForDelegate];
    
    self.partnerServices = [[PBPartnersServices alloc] init];

}

Comment: You may as well move `preareForDelegate` into the `init` method.  Anyway does the `respondsToSelector` line get run? (use a breakpoint).

Comment: I bet something is nil.  You have to have 2 object created and retained in memory.  So if the delegate gets released in memory, the delegate variable will goto nil, and the code behavior will not change expect the delegate method will never execute.

Comment: I moved prepareForDelegate in init and it still not work. Maybe it can help: I call my delegated method in success block of http request.

Comment: I made Github repository https://github.com/alex3165/parisbruxelles

Comment: You allocate self.partnerService twice. What's happen when you delete the second allocation (after [self.ticketsServices prepareForDelegate]; ?

Comment: "(when I print self.delegate I get 'nil')" -- That's a big clue.  It means that self.delegate doesn't address an object, either because you never created the delegate object or because you set the `delegate` property in a different instance of your calling  object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): either add `ticketsService` as an argument of your `partnerServices` constructor, or do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate the partnerServices property a second time your partnerServices will save in a new memory-adress. And for this object you didn't set the delegate property.

Comment: Ok thanks you I solved it by passing my partnerServices to my TicketsServices in my HomeController :

self.ticketsServices = [[PBTicketsService alloc] initWithpartnersServices:self.partnerServices];